# VB/C#.NET & DataGridViewGrouper - How to make the DLL run in VB?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll

I am refering to this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/995958/DataGridViewGrouper

I want to use this DataGridViewGrouper on our VB.NET project.

It's working fine when I am using it on a C# project, but it doesn't on a VB project.

I am adding the DLL ( DataGridViewGrouper\obj\Debug\DataGridViewGrouper.DLL ) as a reference to my project. And yet, it complains that there is no namespace like "Subro".

I remember adding PostSHARP as a DLL to our project the same way, and it worked fine.

What might be the reason this ain't be working?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Add the project to the solution and then reference to it, it should work fine.

Comment: Sorry to hear you had to give up on the component. Having written the component I was curious and tried it in a vb.net program, but it worked without problems right away. (also sorry for my late reply if it was you who asked the question at the project itself, I wasn't paying attention to updates to it). But as user666 suggested, it probably is a framework difference matter. Since you are using ObjectListView (looks pretty cool), you won't need help on this matter, but in case you do, post a comment with @me.name ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the assembly is compatible with CLS.
Write [assembly: CLSCompliant(true)] in your code.
[See more here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/En-us/library/12a7a7h3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also make sure that the version of NetFramework in your assembly is less or equal version of your main project

Comment: I have added that line to the C# code, above "namespace Subro.Controls", I wrote  "[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]". Funny, because when I compile it, and use that new DLL as a reference in VB, the suggestions that pop up when I start typing showing me the namespaces and the method "DataGridViewGrouper", but when I want to start the program, it pretends it doesn't know anything of it.

Comment: Then check the version of .Net assembly in C# and VB.

Comment: I have found "<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")>" in the AssemblyInfo.vb. The C# project I have downloaded from codeproject has the equivalent line "[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]".

Comment: emm... version of .NET Framework it is not a version of assembly... Go to Project's Property Pages > Build > Target Framework or Properties > Application > Target Framework (depending on project type)

Comment: We gave it up and replaced the DataGridView by something called ObjectListView control. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yesssss, thank you user666. Changing the target framework on the grouper project to 4.0 worked for me on this (compiling to same as my project didn't work for some reason).    To clarify;  Project Properties > Application > Target Framework... rebuild and use new dll.

Also thank you DougyDoug, I'm now looking at ObjectListView and making plans to implement it elsewhere.